# Where should I update_options in a theme?

Tags: theme-development, customization, options

I am designing a theme where the home page (i.e. `is_home()`) should only display the latest blog post. I want to do something like `$wp_query->update_option('posts_per_page', 1)` every time I am on the home page. All other pages that display posts (like archives) should just follow the user defined option.

This seems a bit unnecessary to do every single time since the option should just be set once, right? Is it possible within The Loop to just ignore the user-set option of `posts_per_page` and force `have_posts()` to just be set to one post?

In general, where should this kind of "set-it-once" stuff go? I don't really think it should be a plug-in because it is theme specific. I also don't want to mess with the user's options which is why `update_option` isn't the best choice for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate approach (if you want/need to keep this in functions.php and go via hooks instead of modifying template) would be something like this:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'pre_get_posts_home' );

function pre_get_posts_home( $query ) {

    global $wp_query;

    if( $wp_query == $query && $query->is_home )
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 );
}
```

Comment: Where can I find a canonical list of filter/action hooks? (http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/) doesn't list `pre_get_posts`, nor does the Codex mention it on (http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference).

Comment: I did a little more research and noticed that on the Codex, `pre_get_posts` (I thought it was a filter so I looked for it as a filter) is identified as an action. Is there a difference in the above code between calling `add_filter` vs `add_action`? The difference in semantics on the Codex isn't quite clear to me.

Comment: @Avry ah, sorry, should be `add_action()` indeed :) The difference is that filter expects and uses returned value, action does not. But technically `add_filter()` and `add_action()` are identical (in fact one of those just calls another) and distinction is for human convenience, not code. Edited snippet.

Answer (score 1):

`posts_per_page` should be set once the at settings reading panel, and acts as a general option unless defined else using [query_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) for example if you want your homepage to display only one then the place this code above your loop:

```
if (is_home()){ // conditional check for homepage
    global $query_string;
    parse_str( $query_string, $args );
    $args['posts_per_page'] = 1;
    query_posts( $args );
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `$args['posts_per_page'] = 1;` ? :)

Comment: Where should this code snippet go? In loop.php?

Comment: like i posted in my answer, just above the loop

Answer (score 0):

I prefer use a function than use global variable, like this:

```
if (is_home()) set_query_var('posts_per_page', 1);
```